# smtp server requires authentication but I believe it already has it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I get a message saying the server requires authentication when i get to the bottom line of the following code block.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("me@myemail.co.uk");

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@myToAddress.co.uk"));

message.Subject = "Message subject";
message.Body = "This is the content";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

However, I thought I had already given it the info it requires in webconfig as follows:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="me@myemail.co.uk">
    <network host="mySMTPserver" port="25" userName="myEmail" password="myPass" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Any advice much appreciated, I read many posts on here and they all seem to be providing the login in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

SET
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false

SET port:

```
 client.Port = 587
```

These properties can also be set in the .config file

To understand why 587, see
http://mostlygeek.com/tech/smtp-on-port-587/

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, it certainly has changed things and your port advice is great to know.  However it is now giving me the following error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" - I'm unsure if the port is causing that

Comment: Please try setting the port back to 25.

Comment: This solved the problem for me when I used one of my other SMTP servers.  Many thanks for your time :)